# How to test a function in angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8

This is really simple function in app component and need to write test case for it.

Code that I have tried.

**app.component.html**

```
<button
    class="click"
    (click)="clickHandler('dummy data')"
  >
    Click Here
  </button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'root-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

clickHandler(value: string) {
    if (value) {
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the test that I have tried for the above code,

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
  it('should check clickHandler function', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'clickHandler');
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

I am not sure whether these many things needed to check whether the function is there.

**Requirement:** I am in the need to write test case to check `clickHandler` function in app component.

For which I have tried the above, and this results in success case but still I have the test coverage error like,

[image]

How can I get rid of this error while viewing the test coverage.

**Edit:**

Based on @Gérôme Grignon answer, the things working if I modify the `app.component.ts` file but I **cannot** modify the file and I need to work only in `app.component.spec.ts` file and hence can anyone suggest the way to handle only **truthy** value as like I mentioned above.

```
    clickHandler(value: string) {
      if (value) {
      }
    }
```

For which I have tried like,

```
expect(component.clickHandler('foo')).toBeTruthy();
expect(component.clickHandler('bar')).toBeFalsy();
```

But I get error like,

> Expected true not to equal true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here you are doing an integration test : you don't test the function but the integration between the component and the template.

Here is an exemple to test your function (adding some random logic) :

```
clickHandler(value: string) {
  if (value === 'foo') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```
it('should return value', () => {
expect(component.clickHandler('foo')).toEqual(true);
expect(component.clickHandler('bar')).not.toEqual(true);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and what should I need to do here if only need to check if there is value and not comparison like ```if (value === 'foo')```

Comment: If I give ```if(value)``` then it is throwing error ```Expected true not to equal true.``` ..

Comment: Can you please help me to check only value is truthy and not comparison? If that is done it is okay.. Because I am supposed to not make any change in ```component.ts``` file ..

Comment: Could you provide more information about your use case? What's the goal of this function? why can't you modify the component file?

Comment: Someone is writing the ```ts``` file and hence I am given the task to only write test case for the given scenario and not to modify the component.ts file..

Comment: For now I will accept your solution but I would also like to know from you to cover the above given case.

Comment: Can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909809/how-to-write-unit-test-for-snackbar-in-angular

Comment: I understand. Rather than sticking to delivering a test, i advice you to question the goal of the test and so on the goal of the function. In this example, the function is clearly pointless : the point of a condition is to add a specific behavior if it matchs the condition. As the condition block is empty and there is no more code inside the function, the function doesn't do anything at all. So to be clear : there is no way to test such a function as a test need some type of result expectation ( it might invocate another function, it might return a value...).

Comment: Here as you did correctly, the only thing you can test is the integration with the template but you arn't able to test the function directly.

Comment: Got your point and I will take this to my team and will inform them it is pointless to test this now.. Also can you give solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909809/how-to-write-unit-test-for-snackbar-in-angular which has valid code..

Comment: Consider the function is may be incomplete or there is a missing commit. But as you need to test any new content, it would be a good advice to tell them to only commit testable content.

Comment: Posted a new question with more explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61913015/13270726